# Showing that the unique function satisfying $f''(x)=\alpha f(x)$ is $e^{\sqrt{\alpha}x}$, $\alpha>0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

I am trying to avoid doing some tedious case work on an optimization problem and I think this is true but I am struggling to prove it.

I have seen the proof of 
$\begin{equation*}
f'=af
\end{equation*}$
being uniquely satisfied by $ce^{ax}$ up to scaling proved by differentiating the quotient, but similar techniques dont seem to work here. Beyond asserting it is true by the theorem for existence and uniqueness, is there a simple way to show this?

Comment: This is not true: Consider $e^{-\sqrt{\alpha} x}$, and linear combinations of these two solutions. (This all assumes, by the way, that $\alpha > 0$.)

Comment: There will be two independent solutions, corresponding to the two square roots of $a$. If $a$ is negative you need complex exponentials - that is, sines and cosines - and you have simple harmonic motion.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that, $\alpha>0$ by assumption, will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniqueness of a solution of a differential equation can only hold if initial/boundary conditions are specified. If you specify $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(0) = \sqrt{\alpha}$, then $f(x) = e^{\sqrt{\alpha}x}$ is the unique solution to the ODE. Other initial/boundary conditions will generally give a different solution.

So, yes, you can invoke the existence and uniqueness theorem, but an integral part of that theorem is the existence of predescribed initial conditions.

Comment: The conditions on this problem are that $f \in C^{2}[a,b]$ for some interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and I am trying to prove that |f(x)| ≤ max{|f(a)|, |f(b)|}, I think what this problem is getting at is the minimal conclusions you can make without initial conditions.

Comment: Then, without boundary conditions, you will need the *general solution* to this ODE, which shouldn't be difficult to obtain.

Comment: @qbert if that's what you really want to show, all you need to show is $f''$ or $f$ cannot change sign, I.e the function is convex, zero or concave throughout the interval.